# Iterative multidimensional associative array using foreach loop in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I want to search a particular record in a multidimensional associative array. It works fine when I search a record from the first array but it is not working properly when searching in the second array.

This is my code:

```
<?php
$year= array("January"=>array("Ben","Katty","Paul"),
"December"=>array("Ali","Adnan","Sajjad")
);
$match="Ali";
$notThere = True;

foreach ($year as $month => $person) {
    foreach ($person as $subjectName => $ID) {
        if($match==$ID){        
            echo "${ID}. borns on ${month}<br>";
            $notThere = false;
        }
    }
    if($notThere){
        echo "Not Found";
        $notThere=false;
    }   
}
?>
```

**Not FoundAli. borns on December**

Also, if you could explain how a nested `foreach` loop works.

Comment: What output are you expecting

Comment: not working show 0 born on january 0 born on December..

Comment: i want is show not found or in case of true Ali born on January

Comment: but acc. to array Ali is born in Dec

Comment: first it output not found..then ali is born on December.. why it show not found first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your If statement out of loops

```
<?php
$year= array("January"=>array("Ben","Katty","Paul"),
"December"=>array("Ali","Adnan","Sajjad")
);
$match="Ali";
$notThere = True;

foreach ($year as $month => $person) {
    foreach ($person as $subjectName => $ID) {
        if($match==$ID){        
            echo "${ID}. borns on ${month}<br>";
            $notThere = false;
        }
    }
}
if($notThere){
    echo "Not Found";
    $notThere=false;
}   
?>
```

Comment: Thanks now its work please explain how this nested loop work.. once i get key and value what need of another loop..

Comment: second loop iterate over the array( which contain names) of first loop